# How to indent with tabs in php-mode?

Tags: indentation, tabs, php-mode

I need to indent my code with `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'php-enable-symfony2-coding-style)` but using tabs for indenting (and spaces for aligning, see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartTabs). Apparently the coding styles of php-mode overrides emacs tab settings, because I have the next code in my emacs init file, but the spacebar indenting prevails nonetheless:

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-width 4)
```

Tabs were working before using php-mode.

Example of the indentation I use:

```
// Indenting with tabs
if (false
    || true
    || true
) {
    $hi = [
        'la',
        'do' => 5,
    ];

    $foo
        -> mi(
            54,
            57
        )

        -> fa()
    ;
} else {
    $lala =
        (new lala)
            -> hey()
            -> ho()
    ;

    $sup = work([
        'it' => 1,
        'faster' => 6,
    ]);

    // Aligning with spaces
    $a··· = 1;
    $ab·· = 2;
    $abcd = 4;
}
```

I am using `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'php-enable-symfony2-coding-style)` because it is the most similar amongst the php-mode available styles. Maybe I should turn off php-mode indentation and use other indentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I was leaning how *php-mode* handles indentation, and also I looked into `php-mode.el`:

The problem was that `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'php-enable-symfony2-coding-style)` sets:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil
        fill-column 78
        c-indent-comments-syntactically-p t
        require-final-newline t)
```

... before `(c-set-style "symfony2")`, so it is overriding how you configured `indent-tabs-mode` before.

To solve the problem, you can just discard `php-enable-symfony2-coding-style` and use:

```
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook '(lambda ()
                            (setq tab-width 4
                                  indent-tabs-mode t)
                            (c-set-style "symfony2")
                            ))
```